# RegEx, Substituting a variable number of replacements

Tags: regex, perl

Hopefully I'm missing something obvious.

I've got a file that contains some lines like:

```
| A | B | C |
|-----------|
Ignore this line
| And | Ignore | This |
| D | E | F | G |
|---------------|
```

I want to find the `|----|` lines, remove those... and replace all of the `|` characters with a `^` in the preceding line. e.g.

```
^ A ^ B ^ C ^
Ignore this line
| And | Ignore | This |
^ D ^ E ^ F ^ G ^
```

So far I've got:

```
perl -0pe 's/^(\|.*\|)\n\|-+\|/$1/mg'
```

This takes input from stdin (some other modifications have already happened with `sed`)... and it's using `-0` and `/m` to support multiline replacements.

The match seems to be correct, and it removes the `|----|` lines, but I can't see how I can do the `|` to `^` substitution with the `$1` (or `\1`) backreference.

I can't remember where I did it before, but another language allowed me to use `${1/A/B}` to substitute A to B, but that's upsetting perl.

And I've been wondering if this is where `/e` or `/ee` could be used, but I'm not familiar enough with perl on how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```perl
perl -0pe 's{^(.*)\R\|-+\|$\R?}{$1 =~ s,\|,^,gr}gme' t
```

Details:

- `^(.*)\R\|-+\|$\R?` - matches all occurrences (see the `g` flag at the end)

  - `^` - start of a line (note the `m` flag that makes `^` match start of a line and `$` match end of a line)
  - `(.*)` - Group 1: whole line
  - `\R` - a line break sequence
  - `\|` - `|` char
  - `-+` - one or more `-` chars
  - `\|` - a `|` char
  - `$` - end of line
  - `\R?` - an optional line break sequence.

Once the match is found, all `|` are replaced with `^` using `$1 =~ s,\|,^,gr`, that replaces inside the Group 1 value. This syntax is enabled with the `e` flag.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Wiktor, I’ll have to finish it tomorrow (was my last ditch effort for the day, and not at my computer now), but that looks like it will work (from my limited understanding of Perl).

Comment: @CraigFrancis I tested in Ubuntu 18.04 with a file named `t`. If you want to modify the `t` file you need to add `-i` option: `perl -i -0pe 's{^(.*)\R\|-+\|$\R?}{$1 =~ s,\|,^,gr}gme' t`

Comment: Thank you for this, it works perfectly, and gives me a nice example on how to use the evaluate modifier.

Answer (score 2):

I could see this being done using 2 substitutions:

```perl
\|(?=.*[\r\n]+\|-+\|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/x7d15d/1/

And then:

```perl
^\|-+\|(?:[\r\n]+|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZdEzuM/1/

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyZeus, I’ll have to check tomorrow now (ran away from computer), and while I think Wiktor’s solution might be my preference (because I think it does it in 1 go), I’ll still see if this works as well (I was really getting stuck on the undefined number of substitutions, which I think you’ve solved).

Comment: @CraigFrancis I have no doubt that Wiktor's answer works. I was half way through mine when Wiktor answered but just wanted to show what us mere regex mortals can achieve. Having 2 solutions never hurts =)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Let me note that I am also a mere regex mortal :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If we're on the same plane then I will cherish that statement as a compliment =)

Comment: Just for my own understanding, why does the first one start '(?=\|).' ... I'm just wondering if could just be '\|', as I'm not sure what the positive lookahead assertion is being used for (the rest makes perfect sense, and thanks again).

Comment: @CraigFrancis I can confidently say that I have no idea why I chose to start the regex with a lookahead. I probably started with one plan in mind but as I wrote the regex a different path took hold and I never re-assessed the beginning since it just worked =)

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyZeus, that's usually what happens for me... and thanks for updating the answer to start with `\|`, I think that makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

With one pattern that checks the next line in a lookahead assertion:

```
perl -0pe 's/\|(?=.*\R\|-+\|$)(?:\R.*)?/^/gm' file
```

If you absolutely want to use an evaluation, you can put a transliteration in the replacement part with this pattern:

```
perl -0pe 's#^(.*)\R\|-+\|$#$1=~y/|/^/r#gme' file
```

Comment: Thank you Casimir, can you explain a bit for me... I get the initial `\|` match, and the `(?=.*\R\|-+\|$)` look ahead to the next line... but the non-capturing sub pattern `(?:\R.*)?`, which optionally matches/includes the next line, I can see how that works with the first match; but if that happens, won't that remove the '|----|' line? So how does the second "|" match work with the subsequent line now missing? (this is just down to me not knowing how the Perl RegEx engine works)

Comment: @CraigFrancis: That is all the trick! The `(?:\R.*)?` succeeds only when the last character (the last `|`) of the line is reached. In your example `| A | B | C |`, `(?:\R.*)?` fails with the three first pipes (due to the `\R` newline sequence alias), because the end of the line isn't reached. The next line is removed only when the last pipe is reached.

Comment: Oh, wow, yes, I see it, so the first set of pipes are replaced by them matching the pipe and the "positive lookahead assertion" just checks for the next line, but doesen't actually replace it... whereas the last pipe, while it does the same, it also matches the line following directly afterwards, so it can finish the process by removing it... that's clever.

Comment: @CraigFrancis: Yes, you get it. The price of this method is that you have to check the lookahead at each pipe, but since the pattern starts with a literal character (the pipe), positions where there are pipes are found with a quick algorithm and the pattern is only tested at these positions (instead of all positions in the string).